# How to create report and graph for two fields?

Tags: dashboard, custom-report-type

I selected  fields from many fields of an object, that are, 1) Name(String) 2)Status(Percentage)
How can I create its report & graph?

Issues:

I am trying but I have to group by a column to create graph. 
Percentage value shows 1 instead of its actual value. For example, status has value equal to 70% but it shows its value 1 in the graph.

Comment: Could you please elaborate completely on your issue... because the result will come perfectly if you give with the percentage and field

Comment: The reason your graph shows a value of 1 is probably because it is showing record count. You have to summarize the percentage field in the report to be able to show the percentage in the graph

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new report with the appropriate report type
2. Drag the fields you want to show on the preview pane
3. Make it a summary report (picklist in preview pane)
4. Group on your 'Name' field
5. Summarize the percentage field (arrow on the percentage field)
6. Click the 'add chart' button
7. Change 'record count' in the dropdown list to your 'percentage field'

That's it. I recommend you to work your way through the [reporting workbook](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/workbook_analytics.pdf). You will learn pretty much everything there is to know about reports and dashboards.